# Matching PLSQL "declare" block with Java regex

Tags: java, regex, plsql

Say i have a sql file with several declare statements inside:

```
declare
   --some code here
begin
   -- some code here
   begin
     -- some code here (may contain begin/end blocks as well)
   end;
   begin
     -- some code here
   end;
end;

declare
begin
    -- some code here
end;
```

I want to be able to match the two "declare" statements inside with a Java regex expression. The problem here is the nested begin/end blocks, there is no limit in how deep the nesting can go.

I know similar questions have been asked here, like how to match sql statements in a file, but i think this construct is a bit more controllable in terms of regex than plain sql statements.

Comment: To match `begin` with the correct `end` you'll need either [recursive regexes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) or [nested regexes](https://retkomma.wordpress.com/2007/10/30/nested-regular-expressions-explained/). I'm not sure which of those (if either) is supported by your Java version.

Comment: i am trying to use the FLEX tokenizer (http://flex.sourceforge.net/). I think this adds some sort of recursivity support, using underlying java regex though.

Comment: i meant http://jflex.de in my previous comment